# Getting error when trying to add SkyEpub reader

Tags: android

This is the code that i have tried to implement SkyEpub Reader and adding books to it.

```
public boolean makeBooksDirectory() {
        boolean res;
        String filePath = new String(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/books");
        Log.d("Debug", filePath);
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            res = file.mkdirs();
            Log.d("Land",file.getPath());
        }else {
            res = false;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public boolean fileExists(String fileName) {
        boolean res;

        String pureName = this.removeExtention(fileName);
        String targetDirectory = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/books/"+pureName;
        String targetPath = targetDirectory+"/"+ fileName;

        File file = new File(targetPath);
        debug(file.getAbsolutePath());

        if (file.exists()) res = true;
        else  res = false;
        return res;
    }
```

But When i tried to run it, it shows following error. I cant understand if should i need to make book folder anywhere?

Error:

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request  D/Debug: /data/user/0/com.App/files/books

08-30 19:43:34.425 15819-15819/com.App D/EPub: faild to make books directory

08-30 19:43:34.457 15819-15819/com.App D/PhoneWindow: notifyNavigationBarColor, color=0x: ff000000, token: android.view.ViewRootImplAO$WEx@4064635

08-30 19:43:34.629 15819-15819/com.App V/ViewRootImpl: Contents drawing finished : com.App/com.App.activities.EPubActivity
08-30 19:43:34.671 15819-15877/com.App E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa5d062e0
```

Comment: Where is the code that prints "faild to make books directory"?

Comment: I suggest you use the Android Studio debugger to determine why this happens.

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_epubreader);

        btnbook = (Button)findViewById(R.id.book);
        btninstall = (Button)findViewById(R.id.install);

        if (!this.makeBooksDirectory()) {
            debug("faild to make books directory");
        }

        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float density = metrics.density;

        contentView = new RelativeLayout(this);

Comment: Please edit your question so you can format the code properly

Comment: It should create folder if it doesn't exist. Path will be AppFolder/books